# Автоматическое переключение слайдов по маршруту

Tags: arduino, автоматизация, электроника

Короче, суть такая есть планшет на рельсе который можно передвигать вручную вдоль стены, по маршруту есть места где нужно чтобы переключился слайд. Мы нашли решение в виде платы Ардуино как HID клавиатура, которая в зависимости от расстояния будет имитировать нажатия стрелочек вправо и влево соответственно. Есть ли способы сделать все проще, может какое то ПО которое решит такую проблему.

PS. Есть стена с картинами и планшет на рельсе который двигается вдоль стены, находясь под картиной он должен выводить информацию о ней. Как проще всего сделать определение местоположения и переключение слайдов

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Понял. Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: Куда это hid устройство подключаете? Вообще, чем это все управляется?

Comment: Мне предложили такой вариант, тип usb через переходник в планшет и таким образом управляется. Управляться должно автоматически в зависимости от положения на рельсе.
Мне вообще такой вариант не нравится потому и задал вопрос, может что получше предложите

Comment: Ну, тут большой простор для творчества. Можно под картиной наклеить qr-код со ссылкой, планшет снимает его, открывает ссылку, по ссылке нужная информация. hid-устройство - тоже вполне нормальный вариант, по крайней мере достаточно простой в осуществлении. Можно какое-то bluetooth устройство также эмулировать, но это скорее всего будет сложнее.